# warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

Tags: compiler-warnings

Why do I get this compiler warning message on lines 2-6?

warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

```
inline float SIGN(const double &a, const float &b)
    {return b >= 0 ? (a >= 0 ? a : -a) : (a >= 0 ? -a : a);}
inline float pow (float x, double y) {return pow(double(x),y);}
inline float pow (double x, float y) {return pow(x,double(y));}
inline float atan2 (float x, double y) {return atan2(double(x),y);}
inline float atan2 (double x, float y) {return atan2(x,double(y));}
```

Comment: Obviously because your functions return a float when the computed expression is of type double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++, the `float` type is lower precision than the `double` type. You have declared your functions as returning floats, but the functions are working with doubles. The rules of mixing numerical types apply here, and some types get converted, silently, as you combine them.

The results of your functions, as calculated inside them, are doubles which you then return from the functions as floats. The compiler is warning you that it is possible that the value in the double type you are returning from inside your function will not fit in the functions' return type  `float` properly, and some precision may be lost in the conversion. It does not otherwise explicitly warn you about mixing float and double. But it might if you mixed `int` and `double`.

There is little value to using float types on modern (younger than 10 years) desktop or server hardware.

Comment: Yes I see... I got the warnings from this header file: numerical.recipes/pubdom/nrutil_nr.h.txt - do you expect they intended to have this warning in the code or made an error not to return a double? Would there be a good reason to keep them as float?

Comment: When the original Numerical Recipes  (in C?) was written float and double had performance/precision trade-offs that were useful. My guess is that this is just old code. Boost and the GNU projects all offer modern numerical calculation libraries.